# Casting DBNull to boolean

Tags: c#

Hello I can't seems to solve this cast operation. I get error:

> String not recognized as a valid boolean

for the line

```
isKey = Convert.ToBoolean(row["IsKey"].ToString());
```

I'm using a `DataReader` to get my table Schema. `IsKey` is presently `null` everywhere in my DB. I basically want a `true` or `false` result.

```
tableSchema = myReader.GetSchemaTable();     

foreach (DataRow row in tableSchema.Rows)
{
    string columnName = row["ColumnName"].ToString();
    string columnType = row["DataTypeName"].ToString();               
    bool isKey = Convert.ToBoolean(row["IsKey"].ToString());
```

Comment: A null isn't a boolean type, use nullable `bool?`. However you `ToString()` everything anyhow so that still won't work.

Comment: you should use `bool?`

Comment: If it's `DBNull.Value`, what `bool` value do you want to convert to?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

First, use this format for getting values from a `DataRow`:

```
string columnName = row.Field<string>("ColumnName");
string columnType = row.Field<string>("DataTypeName"); 
//this uses your first and second variable call as an example
```

This strongly defines the returning value and does conversion for you.

Your problem is that you have a column that is a `bit` (or at least I hope it's a bit), but also allows `nulls`. This means that the datatype in c# is a `bool?`. Use this:

```
bool? isKey = row.Field<bool?>("IsKey");
```

---

Your second question (in the comments):

> if bool? isKey return NULL how can I convert that to false?

The easiest way is to use a [`Null-Coalescing Operator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx)

```
bool isKey = row.Field<bool?>("IsKey") ?? false;
```

This says: "give me first thing that is not null, either the column value or "false".

Comment: the variable name `columnName` may make someone confused, the value in fact is not `columnName` it's the value of the cell on the `row` at the column `ColumnName`.

Comment: @KingKing, agreed. I was using the first item as example. Expanded to both

Comment: @gunr2171 thank for you help it was helpful. Another question on that: if bool? isKey return NULL how can I convert that to false? According to documentation the isKey value return True or False so I got surprised when it returned a NULL, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getschematable.aspx

Comment: @ElieEl-Tawil, glad to help. See my updated answer for your second question.